# how to apply max height and enable scroll to Xamarin.Forms.Editor

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, editor, xamarin.forms

I wanted chat application type user interface in my app & i am targeting android and iOS.
I am using Xamarin.Forms.Editor for reply

```
Editor _replyEntry = new Editor
{
  HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
  TextColor = Color.Black
}
```

in this case the editor height remains constant and allows scrolling and editor does not expands

Then i used InvalidateMeasure()

```
_replyEntry .TextChanged += (sender, e) => { this.InvalidateMeasure(); };
```

in this case editor expands as when the text requires more space but does not allow scroll inside editor and if user types long message then editor does not allows scroll and text goes behind the keyboard and not visible to user

Is there any way to enable scroll and give max height to edit either in xamarin.forms of by writing custom renderer

Thanks

Here is my code

```
public class abc : ContentPage
{
  public abc()
  {
    Image attchment = new Image
    {
      Source = "attachment.png",
      HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start
    };

    Editor _replyEntry = new Editor
    {
      HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
      TextColor = Color.Black,
    };

    Button _sendButton = new Button
    {
      Text = "Send",
      TextColor = Color.Black,
      BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
      HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End
    };

    StackLayout replyStack = new StackLayout
    {
      Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
      Padding = new Thickness(10),
      Spacing = 10,
      VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
      Children = { attchment, _replyEntry, _sendButton }
    };
    Content = replyStack;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your full code, as its not all that clear what your actually wanting.  What are you hosting your Editor in?

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions here - https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/38172/how-to-autosize-editor-height.  It looks like you will have to possibly write a custom renderer though to get exactly what you want?

Comment: i tried this but in that case i am not able to get scroll bar and also not able apply max height that is why the large text goes under the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you will have to use a custom renderer to achieve what you are wanting.

There is a post [here](http://harisankar-krishnaswamy.blogspot.it/2013/07/android-ui-scrollable-edit-text-with-ok.html) that has pretty much the same thing with what you are trying to achieve for `Android`.

In that demo it has an expanding multi-line `EditText` control (`android:singleLine="false"`), with only vertical scrollbars (`android:scrollbars="vertical"`), whilst disabling the horizontal scrollbars (`android:scrollHorizontally="false"`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the Editor' parent is expanding, then the editor will automatically expand too. If you make an empty contentpage and add an Editor, the is will just expand. If you place it inside a stacklayout, the you need to ensure that the stacklayout is expanding.